# Get and return result from php exec

Tags: php, exec

Hi I want to run external php script , send paramter like string and get result, array result

my exec is :

```
exec("php' . 'test.php' ' $test, $retVal);
```

in test php i trying to echo or somethings but it not work

so I want to call php test.php . and get responce true or false with parameters that I send

that script should run in bacgrkound so it have to be shel_exec or exec but it should return string if he got calls by exec

Comment: Is there a reason why you just can't include the file?

Comment: if you need to execute script and return it's value then you should used `include`

Comment: or you can also try for `curl` http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: `it not work` for starters because that is not valid php. Post the real code and errors you get back.

Comment: its script from a different folder with a different framework ,  also the script should get a string if the string is different he should run something else. I updated the question with the main purpose

Comment: @jeroen did not get you . I did not get any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yourfile.php

```
    <?php
        $value = "a";
        exec("php -f test.php $value", $output);
        print_r($output);
        $array = json_decode($output[0], true);
        print($array["foo"]);

        $value = "b";
        exec("php -f test.php $value", $output2);
        print_r($output2);
    ?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    if($argv[1] == "a"){
        $array = array(
            "foo" => "bar",
            "bar" => "foo",
        );
        echo json_encode($array);
    } else {
        echo "it wasn't an a";
    }
?>
```

To obtaint "true" or "false" if the exec succeded :

```
exec("php -f test.php $value", $output, $return); /* print($return) */
```

$output contain everything displayed by the php script, that's why you should use json to display your object and then encode it back in his state.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
exec('php index2.php '.$start.' '.$end);
```

Comment: how do I get array? return is doing nothing 
 and echo is only for string

Comment: exec('php index2.php '.$start.' '.$end.'  ,$output ); try this for output